# Upgrading system motherboard to Gigabyte GA-Z97X-Gaming 3 but I dont have required 8 pin cpu connector

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

My PSU only has a 8(6+2)pin connector, a 4pin connector, a molex connector and sata connector. I tried plugging this into the motherboard only to discover that it doesnt work. I did some googling and discovered that this connector is only for gpu power and not for cpu power.
I went searching and discovered that you are able to get adaptors that convert molex to 8 pin connectors.
Would it be better to get [Molex + 4pin to 8pin(4+4)CPU connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzwnH.png) or [molex to CPU 8 pin (4+4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufXp1.png)

I assume the first option would be better as its power from more sources and using the 4 pin connector which is intended to power cpus in the first place.

Would either of these 2 solutions be suitable?

Comment: how could either of these cables work if your PSU does not have a molex connector?

Comment: The best solution would be a new PSU.

Answer (score 0):

Computer components are designed to work with specific other components, not in a brand to brand way, but in a "family or compatibility" way, usually based around a primary feature such as the specific CPU generation.

While certain components have some flexibility in working with multiple "families of compatibility", and Power Supply Units ("PSUs") tend to be this way more than other components, there are limits.

One of the ways these compatibility families are defined and enforced is the connectors and cables that join them, and of particular importance for the PSU, the cables that connect the PSU to the Main Board ("MB") will define whether that PSU is designed to work with that MB.

Some PSUs will use a "modular" cable design where you can switch the cables out for ones that support a different type of MB and CPU, while others will include adaptable cables or multiple permanent cables where you simply use the one correct for your system.

As your PSU clearly lacks any of these features or options, the correct answer is that your PSU is not designed or intended to power the MB you've chosen, and you should purchase one that is.